# On VPS, How do i assign a configured Static IPv4 address via subnets of the VPS network on OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have a Ubuntu VPS with a static Native IP address 211.xx.xxx.205. I have setup an OpenVPN to route traffic network from the VPS to my Ubuntu local computer.

It is working fine. However, my problem is that, i want a static ip address such as 211.xx.xxx.220 on a client side connection such that the IPV4 address changes to something like 211.xx.xxx.220.I have tried to use the Client-Config-dir under ccd, and the ip shows on my local computer that it changed but there is no internet. The pages on browser loads forever.

I also tried the ippx.txt file where i specifically assigned an ip, but the same as the case of ccd directory. At a point, it changed fine on the tun0 interface and the internet browses fine too, but the IPv4 addresses doesn't change on the browser. I am wondering if there is something i am not doing or is it possible for IPv4 addresses on subnets such this to work?. Maybe the subnet are not properly informed or configured.

Is there a way to do this using VPS server ip address configuration? If there is, How do i configure my OpenVPN to assign a static ip such as 211.xx.xxx.220 just a little different from the original 211.xx.xxx.205